# SQL statement - issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select all email messages from/to email `first@test.com` (***`domain_name.emails.id = 1`***). (As recipient, As sender)

```
id | from            | message
1  | first@test.com  | A
2  | second@test.com | B /* Because second sent email to first */
```

I have:

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM
    domain_name.emails AS a
    INNER JOIN domain_names AS b ON b.ID = a.domain_name_id
    INNER JOIN email.messages AS c ON c.from = ( a.NAME || '@' || b.NAME || '.' || b.domain_id )
    INNER JOIN email.message_recipients AS d ON d.recipient = ( a.NAME || '@' || b.NAME || '.' || b.domain_id )
WHERE
    a.ID = 1;
```

Note: Is "INNER JOIN" right?
I get:

```
id | from           | message
1  | first@test.com | A
```

Tables (only 2 FKs)

email schema is something like LOGs

**domain_name.emails**

```
id | domain_name_id (domain_names.id FK) | name
1  | 1                                   | first
```

**domain_names**

```
id | domain_id | name
1  | com       | test
```

**email.messages**

```
id | from            | message
1  | first@test.com  | A
2  | second@test.com | B
```

**email.message_recipients**

```
id | message_id (email.messages.id FK) | recipient
1  | 1                                 | second@test.com
2  | 2                                 | first@test.com
```

Comment: You should add foreign key in you tables so you could make inner join easier

Comment: what are the relations in this tables?

Comment: @AbdulRasheed - I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this - not tested-:

```
-- In fromTo I merge `TO`s data after `FROM`s data
;with fromTo as (
  select * 
  from email.messages
  union all
  select message_id, recipient, c.message
  from email.message_recipients d
  join email.messages c on c.id = d.message_id
)
select
    c.*
from
    domain_name.emails a
    join domain_names b on b.ID = a.domain_name_id
    join fromTo c on c.from = ( a.NAME || '@' || b.NAME || '.' || b.domain_id )        
where
    a.ID = 1;
```

[**[ SQL Fiddle Demo ]**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fafa8/2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine those 2 tables that hold e-mail addresses:

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM domain_name.emails AS a
INNER JOIN domain_names AS b ON b.ID = a.domain_name_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT id AS message_id, "from" AS address FROM email.messages
            UNION
            SELECT message_id, recipient FROM email.message_recipients
           ) AS m ON m.address = ( a.NAME || '@' || b.NAME || '.' || b.domain_id )
INNER JOIN email.messages AS c ON c.id = m.message_id
WHERE
    a.ID = 1;
```